# How to remove 'mtext' element (if there is no preceded text), within particular msub

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest to identify or remove the mtext with content 'aaaaa' which is first text element (i.e., no preceding::text()[1]) within 'msub' as its ancestor. In Input xml I kept three 'msub's, except second one, first and last mtext to be removed. In third 'msub' preceded::text[1] is 3, but it is not present in third msub. Element 'mtext' may have any parents or ancestor.

Input XML: (indentation or space not given for input xml, because I used 'text()' method)

```
<article><math><msub><mrow><mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--remove it--><mn>2</mn></mrow><mn>3</mn></msub><msub><mrow><mn>23</mn><mfraction><mrow><mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--no need to remove, bcs preceded text is 23 within msub--><mn>2</mn></mrow><mrow><mn>3</mn></mrow></mfraction></mrow></msub><msub><mover><mrow><mrow><mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--remove it, bcs aaaa is first text within msub--><mi>h</mi></mrow></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mover><mn>2</mn></msub></math></article>
```

Input XML: with indents

```
<article>
<math>
    <msub>
    <mrow>
    <mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--remove it-->
    <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mn>3</mn>
    </msub>
    <msub>
    <mrow>
    <mn>23</mn>
    <mfraction>
    <mrow>
    <mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--no need to remove, bcs preceded text is 23 within msub-->
    <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
    <mn>3</mn>
    </mrow>
    </mfraction>
    </mrow>
    </msub>
    <msub>
    <mover>
    <mrow>
    <mrow>
    <mtext>aaaaa</mtext><!--remove it, bcs aaaa is first text within msub-->
    <mi>h</mi>
    </mrow>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
    <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
    </mover>
    <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
</math>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="mtext[contains(., 'aaaaa')]">
      <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="preceding::text()[1][ancestor::msub][normalize-space(.)!='']">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise><del/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Required OutPut:

```
<article>
  <math>
  <msub>
     <mrow>
        <del/>
        <!--remove it--><mn>2</mn>
     </mrow>
     <mn>3</mn>
  </msub>
  <msub>
     <mrow>
        <mn>23</mn>
        <mfraction>
           <mrow>
              <mtext>aaaaa</mtext>
              <!--no need to remove, bcs preceded text is 23 within msub--><mn>2</mn>
           </mrow>
           <mrow>
              <mn>3</mn>
           </mrow>
        </mfraction>
     </mrow>
  </msub>
  <msub>
     <mover>
        <mrow>
           <mrow>
              <del/>
              <!--remove it, bcs aaaa is first text within msub--><mi>h</mi>
           </mrow>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
           <mn>2</mn>
        </mrow>
     </mover>
     <mn>2</mn>
  </msub>
 </math>
</article>
```

With my code, second 'sub' with first 'mtext' unable to remove.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  `mtext` in your example is an **element**, not a **text node**. If text nodes need to be considered, why have your removed them from the given XML input example?

Comment: Sorry, Can I change that element 'mtext' with 'aaaaa' as its first text containing element?. In our project, <mtext>aaaaa</mtext> is representing some space tag (<mspace width="1.0"/>). Later, with help of other program, we are changing that to space. I altered the question. Please suggest.

Comment: I am afraid that's even less clear.

Comment: Please avoid including tags (e.g. "XSLT") in the title. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles.

Comment: Ok, in future posts I will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(previous content removed)*

If I finally(!) understand this correctly, your second template needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="msub//mtext[contains(., 'aaaaa')]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="preceding::*[generate-id(ancestor::msub)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::msub)][text()]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <DELETED/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This will look at the previous elements that are descendants of the **same** `msub` element as the current `mtext`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With the help of your code, I checked all other 'mrow-mtext' nesting conditions. Working fine. Please suggest, what may wrong with my code, there I am checking with respect to 'mtext' and checking whether preceded text found or not, and ensuring its ancestor is 'msub'. But this is failing when two successive 'msub' elements presents. Sorry for my poor question.

Comment: @RudramuniTP I have tried to answer this question in the edit to my post.

Comment: Thank you Sir, for helping me. But second mtext still present, it should be removed. If input changing from '</msub><msub>' to '</msub><other>text</other><msub>'[avoiding successive msub], then my code will removes second mtext also. Once again thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: "*But second mtext still present*" It is present, because the first preceding text node is "3". That's what the `<preceding-text>` element in the output shows. I wasn't trying to fix your code, only to show why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion sir. In such cases how to remove the 'mtext', which is child to msub (text containing first child). Requirement is "removing mtext (as first text containing child) within 'msub'". Once again thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @RudramuniTP Doesn't my first suggestion do what you need? If not, try to explain your requirement in simple, non-technical language. As I told you from the very beginning, the formulation "*removing mtext (as first text containing child) within 'msub'*" makes no sense. `mtext` is not *text* and a *text* cannot contain a child.

Comment: Sir, I want to remove the 'mtext', if it is found within msub as first text containing element. <msub><mrow><mfraction><mtext>aaaa</mtext>, in this case it should be removed. Suppose <msub><mrow><mn>23</mn><mfraction><mtext>aaaa</mtext>, in this case XSLT should not remove, because within msub, <mn> is first text containing element. Sir, is this ok. Sorry sir with my poor presentation method.

Comment: @RudramuniTP In these two examples, is `mtext` a child of `mfraction`? Please edit your question and add these two examples as **complete** XML code.

Comment: @RudramuniTP The thing that confused me is that you write "text containing element" when (I think) you mean "text-containing element". I hope I got it now.

Comment: Yes sir, First Text-containing element.

Comment: Sir, Working perfectly as required. Once again I am asking sorry for my not clear inputs you. By your suggestion, my project will result 100% output.